# Needing to Check for Length Before isdigit() - C++

Tags: c++, memory

I'm solving LeetCode 150. Evaluate Reverse Polish Notation and after a long time of not knowing why my solution wasn't working I checked the answer only to find I was missing a single check for length before using isdigit().

My original code is as follows

```
int evalRPN(vector<string>& tokens) {
    stack<int> nums;
    int num1, num2, num3;

    for(string s : tokens){
        if(isdigit(s[0])){
            nums.push(stoi(s));
            continue;
        }

        num2 = nums.top(); nums.pop();
        num1 = nums.top(); nums.pop();

        num3 = 0;
        if(s == "+"){
            num3 = num1 + num2;
        } else if(s == "-"){
            num3 = num1-num2;
        } else if(s == "*"){
            num3 = num1 * num2;
        } else {
            num3 = num1 / num2;
        }
        nums.push(num3);
    }
    return nums.top();
}
```

and the only change needing to be made is changing the top if statement to

```
if (s.size() > 1 || isdigit(s[0]))
```

I understand that if the length is greater than 1 then it has to be a number and not a math operator, but why does my original solution not work since it checks if the first char is a digit. Without the length check, I get the following memory error

```
runtime error: reference binding to misaligned address 0xbebebebebebec0ba for type 'int', which requires 4 byte alignment (stl_deque.h)
```

I guess what I'm asking is : why does the length of the string need to be checked first to avoid the runtime error.

Thank you

Comment: Can you get negative numbers in this test? Your `isdigit` test would fail for a string like `"-1"`

Comment: `if(isdigit(s[0]))` -- What if `s` is empty?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie As it happens I think that is OK, since `s[0]` would return `'\0'`. Although the code would then fall through and perform a division. I would guess empty strings don't occur in practise

Comment: *I guess what I'm asking is : why does the length of the string need to be checked first to avoid the runtime error.* -- You have the test case that fails (since this is Leetcode), and you have the code.  Why not run your solution in a debugger to see why the error occurs?  A lot of the mystery you could clear up yourself in a matter of minutes by running the code under a debugger.

Comment: When you are treating the string like an array, you should always check the boundary conditions.  You really don't want to access out of bounds locations, as that would be *Undefined Behavior*.

Comment: From observation of what you posted, here are the following potential issues: 1) `s1` is empty.  2) `nums` has no elements, yet `nums.top()` is being called.  3) `num2` is 0, and your code is going into the division logic.  Given the error you received, take your pick as to which one may be occurring.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I wasn't sure so I checked, [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) says it's OK for operator`[]` (but not for `at`)

Comment: @RetiredNinja If `s.empty()` is `true`, then `s.at(0)` will throw since it throws if `pos >= size()` but `s[0]` will be a reference to the `\0` at the end of the string - and it's perfectly ok and defined behavior. Only if `pos > size()` is `s[pos]` undefined behavior. (since C++11)

Answer (score 0):

I do see the same error running your code in LeetCode. However, when I ran the provided Example #3 in Visual Studio, I got an exception for calling `back()` on empty queue.

The explanation: for the sample starting with

```
"10","6","9","3","+","-11","*","/","*" ...
```

Your code doesn't recognize `"-11"` as a number, so it falls through to the operator processing (`if` statement), where if goes to the default clause and treated as `"/"` (not really important).

For every found operator you have two `pop`s from your stack so you ran out of numbers there.

The entire error message from `gcc` is:

> Line 171: Char 16: runtime error: reference binding to misaligned address 0xbebebebebebec0ba for type 'int', which requires 4 byte alignment (stl_deque.h)
> 0xbebebebebebec0ba: note: pointer points here
>
> SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_deque.h:180:16

where `0xbebebebebebec0ba` is likely a content of memory below the head of the queue. The error is still strange, as `0xba` *IS* divisible by 4... BUT, the reference to the source has `x86_64-linux-gnu` in it, so they probably had to complain about 8 byte alignment, which `0xba` is NOT aligned to.

Answer (score 0):

Use of out of bounds index on most STL containers(including `std::string`) leads to undefined behavior. If the container is empty(`c.empty()` or `empty(c)` or `c.size()==0` or `size(c)==0`), then the first element doesn't exist. Remember all those famous memes about the start index of arrays?
For an empty container, even `0` is an out of bounds index. More over, the `front` and `back` functions as well as `*begin(c)` result in undefined behavior on empty containers.